# Graph grouping by and percentages

Tags: excel, graph, pie-chart, linechart

I want to create a chart in Excel but I don't know how is it possible having the table below:

```
ID | MODEL 
==========
1    LG-1
2    HP-2
3    HP-2
4    HP-2
5    LG-1
6    GE
7    HP-1
8    HP-1
9    HP-2
10   HP-2
```

The result I need is a graph showing the percentage of each model in the table 
e.g. in any chart:

```
LG-1  = 20 %
GE    = 10 %
HP-1  = 20 %
HP-2  = 50 %
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere the relative counts of groups (i.e. their percentage shares) need to be calculated so I suggest for Excel 2013 selecting your data range (including labels) and clicking on INSERT > Charts - PivotChart (the down arrow)  and PivotChart then select `Existing Worksheet` entering a suitable `Location:` and <kbd>OK</kbd>. In PivotChart Fields, drag `ID` to VALUES and `MODEL` to AXES. Click on the arrow next to `Sum of ID`, change to `Count of ID` and click on `Value Field Settings...`, on `Show Values As` and select **`Show values as`** "% of Grand Total", OK.

This way I end up with:

[image: SO32728532 example]